# JQuery .serializeArray() drops text after < in input box

Tags: jquery, serializearray

Using .serializeArray()  and if I enter say Jim<Test in a text box, only Jim is picked up by Jquery. Is their a work around?

Thanks!

Comment: code: vFields = $(":input").serializeArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/xyBS3/

I cannot see the code by you,but you can try typing `jim<test` and it will allow you to do that.

Hope it helps the cause. `:)`

**code**

```
$('pre').text(JSON.stringify($('#f').serializeArray(), null, '  '));

$('input').keyup(function() {
    $('pre').text(JSON.stringify($('#f').serializeArray(), null, '  '));
});​
```

Comment: @FrançoisWahl and now you will be remembered for my 10 K points +1 to you as well. `:)`